# BigQuery: Checking for null in conditional expression

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Is it possible to perform a conditional if statement to collapse 3 fields into a single field? I am trying to achieve following. `field1`, `field2` and `field3` are are `Int64` which is *nullable*. I could not find a way to do a null check so am checking if a positive value is assigned to any of the fields then set the a `field` to respective values. When syntax below I am getting error below:

```
case when field1 >= 0 then 0 end as field, 
case when field2 >= 0 then 1 end as field,
case when field3 >= 0 then 2 end as field
```

> Duplicate column names in the result are not supported. Found
>   duplicate(s): field

Comment: Please show us some sample data, ideally in the format of sample input and the expected output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
(case when field1 is not null then 0
      when field2 is not null then 1
      when field3 is not null then 2
 end) as null_check
```

Or, if you want to turn this into a coded field:

```
concat(case when field1 is not null then 0 end,
       case when field2 is not null then 1 end,
       case when field3 is not null then 2 end,
      ) as null_check
```

This will list "0", "1", "2" in a string, depending on the values that are not `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like perhaps you just want a `CASE` expression which can generate multiple values based on multiple conditions:

```
CASE WHEN field3 >= 0 THEN 2
     WHEN field2 >= 0 THEN 1
     WHEN field1 >= 0 THEN 0 END AS field
```

The logic here is that it will check `field3` first, then `field2`, followed by `field1`, when determining which output to generate.